# Limitation of adding a Category from the CP field modal within an entry

Tags: categories, control-panel, field, modal

Is there a way to either add a parent selector to the category field modal, or remove/hide the "+ New Category" button when editing an entry?

We are using a category group to contain Locations, which are nested as State > County > City. I recently noticed that several new Cities have been added to the site, but they are all at the root level instead of being nested under the correct State and County parent categories.

This is because when an author creates a new City via the Location field modal while adding or editing an entry, there is no visible way to specify a parent like there is when adding it from the main Categories CP area.

I can see this getting out-of-hand quickly without some way to keep these categories nested properly, so any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to simply hide that DOM element using [Control Panel CSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss).

Comment: The CPCSS method has solved my immediate problem, but it's certainly possible that the classes or structure of that element could change in a future product update.

My hope is that the Craft team will either add a way to select a parent category from the modal, or add a system setting to hide or disable that button for nested category structures.